# Google Maps Android API v2 limit panning

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-android-api-2

Ok so I have searched the whole internet for a solution, but I had no luck finding the right answer.
So I thought, why not just post the question myself.

**So my situation is as follows:**
I am using the Google Maps API V2 for Android. It's working like a charm as it is right now, but I have to limit panning for only the location that I am using.

**I am using Android Studio.**

I have already made a beginning to make this possible, but I have no clue how I must continue from here.

I hope somebody can help me with this matter.

Thanks in advance!

```
private void setUpMap() {

    /** this is where I made the beginning of the boundary settings **/

    LatLng northEast = new LatLng(52.36060,4.886150);
    LatLng southWest = new LatLng(52.35940, 4.884000);
    LatLngBounds myBoundary = new LatLngBounds(southWest , northEast );
    LatLng mapCenter= new LatLng(52.360011, 4.885216);
    LatLng myLocation= new LatLng(52.360011, 4.885216);

    /** end of boundary settings **/

    mMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);

    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(myLocation)             // Sets the center of the map to Mountain View
            .zoom(19)                   // Sets the zoom
            .bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
            .tilt(30)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
            .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder

    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
}
```

Comment: I have already seen that post. That is not what I am searching for, and I am sure that my code doesn't have to be that long XD

Comment: Never mind. I have resolved my issue myself XD Thanks anyway :)

Comment: You should post an answer to help others!

Comment: I would like to, but I don't see an answer field anywhere. Only this comment field :S Or should I edit my question?

Comment: Ah, you must not have enough reputation to post an answer yet.

Comment: Then I guess this post will stay unanswered untill then lol XD